# how does the cp - f work in Unix?

Tags: cp

I was reading about the `cp` command in unix and one of the options is:

> cp -f : force copy by removing the destination file if needed

so I wanted to test this to see how it works, I did the following:
In some directory as a root I created a file with the name "rootfile":

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Jan  5 20:27 rootfile
```

then as a normal user called "User" I created another file called "Userfile":

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 User User    0 Jan  5 20:27 Userfile
```

now I tried to perform some simple cp of the file "Userfile" to the existing root file named "rootfile" while I logging using the normal user account "User" using the following command:

```
 cp Userfile rootfile
```

and this what I got :

> cp: cannot create regular file `rootfile': Permission denied

This is perfect normal  since I don't have permission to overwrite the existing root file.

Now applying the command with "`-f`" option:

```
cp -f Userfile rootfile
```

all works fine no errors were reported, now my question is how this is possible if i don't have permission to overwrite the file named "rootfile". Is it maybe because I have permission on the folder containing the file? and how does the `-f` option really works?

Regards

Comment: The owner of the directory can, if they have write+execute permissions on the directory, delete any file in it.

Comment: The real question is "why does it normally not remove the file-entry?". The answer: politeness.